# Generar arrays con varios valores, con Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando una "enciclopedia" donde quiero 20 arrays de 5 "huecos" cada uno.

De tal manera que tengo esto porque pienso que funcionaría:

```
var exp=New Array(20);
exp[0][]=["Alfa","alfa.jpg","A","5/8/1993","295"];
exp[1][]=["Beta","beta.jpg","B","5/10/1993","315"];
```

...

De tal manera que introduzca de forma manual entradas sin necesidad de escribir esto:

```
exp[0][0]="Alfa";
exp[0][1]="alfa.jpg";
exp[0][2]="A";
exp[0][3]="5/8/1993";
exp[0][4]="295";
```

...

Pero no me funciona nada y quería saber la forma correcta de generar Arrays con valores "continuos" aunque fuese de forma manual.

Comment: ¿Por qué no lo creas directamente? `let arreglo = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estás casi bien, solo que no necesitas incluir los segundos corchetes (y `new` va todo en minúsculas):

```js
var exp = new Array(20);
exp[0] = ["Alfa","alfa.jpg","A","5/8/1993","295"];
exp[1] = ["Beta","beta.jpg","B","5/10/1993","315"];

console.log(exp[0]);
console.log(exp[0][0]);
console.log(exp[1]);
console.log(exp[1][0]);
```

Comment: Gracias! se vé que tuve un mal dia y no supe verlo bien. Funciona perfecto

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con:

```
exp=[];
exp.push(["Alfa","alfa.jpg","A","5/8/1993","295"]);
exp.push(["Beta","beta.jpg","B","5/10/1993","315"]);
```

Comment: Gracias! La idea del "push" es interesante para no tener que colocar números. Funciona genial!

Comment: Me dio la sensación de que era lo que buscabas al verte los corchetes `[]` que se usan en PHP con esa misma finalidad :)

Answer (score 1):

Esto debería funcionarte:

```js
var exp = [];

exp[0]=["Alfa","alfa.jpg","A","5/8/1993","295"];

console.log(exp[0][0]);
```

Comment: Algo tan sencillo y que me ha dado tantos quebraderos de cabeza ... muchas gracias!